# Why cant i print my statement or anything in here?

Tags: java

like my question is that why is it not able to print even the hi - print statement inside?

```
public class Processor {

      Random random = new Random();

class Process {
        int proId, prior, BurstLength;
    }

    ArrayList<Process> processList;
public static void main(String arg[]) {
}
    public Processor() {
    System.out.println("hi");

        processList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i< 5 ; i++){
            Process newProcess = new Process();
            int temp;
            l1:while(true){
            int rand = 10 - 0;
                temp = random.nextInt(rand)+0;
                System.out.println(temp);
                for (Process p:processList)
                    if (p.proId == temp)
                        continue l1;

                break;
            }
            newProcess.proId = temp;
            newProcess.prior = (int)Math.round(Math.random()*9)+1;
            int range = 100 - 20 + 1;
            newProcess.BurstLength = random.nextInt(range) + 20;
            System.out.println("Process id\tPriority\tburst length");
             System.out.println(newProcess.proId+"\t"+newProcess.prior+"\t"+newProcess.BurstLength);
        }

             }
    }
```

Comment: You have nothing inside your `main`

Comment: `public Processor() {` change to `Processor p = new Processor()` ... other lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `main` method does not contain anything.

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {
     // NOTHING HERE
}
```

So to be able to print "hi" you should declare and initialize your `Processor` class inside your main method by doing this.

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {
     Processor p = new Processor();
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
hi
0
Process id  Priority    burst length
0   6   98
9
Process id  Priority    burst length
9   6   42
2
Process id  Priority    burst length
2   3   84
9
Process id  Priority    burst length
9   2   86
5
Process id  Priority    burst length
5   4   70
```

Comment: Okay, I see what you are trying to say, but when I try to print out the processid, burst length print statement a the bottom I was not able to like getting this errors

Comment: Processor.java:21: error: <identifier> expected
        processList = new ArrayList<>();
                   ^
Processor.java:23: error: illegal start of type
        for (int i = 0; i< 5 ; i++){
        ^
Processor.java:23: error: ')' expected
        for (int i = 0; i< 5 ; i++){
                  ^
Processor.java:23: error: illegal start of type
        for (int i = 0; i< 5 ; i++){
                     ^

Comment: Like how can i print it all inside the main method ?

Comment: I don't understand your comment but when I tried to run your code, it doesn't generate an error.

Comment: Yeh see that is my exact question like why doesn't it print out some kind of output like in the print methods?

Comment: It prints an output. I will edit my answer to include the output

Comment: But then why am I not getting that same output ?

Comment: all it does is prints out "operation complete" and that's it

Comment: Is your code in your environment the same as the code from your post?

Comment: Yes it is the exact same thing i even tried copying that and running it like three times and still nothing, just same thing over and over "operation complete"

Comment: Have you added ```Processor p = new Processor();``` in your main method?

Comment: Oh yeh it worked thank you, actually i did not add Processor p = new Processor(); in the main method

Comment: Oh yeh sure thing

Comment: Well i got one more error the process id part is all messed up like its suppose to print out random numbers without repeation and only once, like no repeating of that random number used only once, but here for some reason its priting out some crazy numbers

Comment: try to search for "how to generate random numbers without duplicates" and combine the solution to your code